# How to get the Text printed in Bitmap to have the same appearance as the text printed in the datagridview cell

Tags: datagridview, bitmap

I have a bitmap, and into this bitmap I print a text using drawstring. The font and forecolor (brush) used in drawstring is the same as the datagridview cell (using DataGridViewCellStyle to refer to the font and forecolor), however the text in the bitmap appears bolder than the text appeared in the datagridview cell and font does not have the same look and feel. Maybe because bitmap is a graphic text and datagridview cell is not? How to get text in bitmap has the same appearance that text in datagridview cell?
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridViewTextBoxCell uses TextRenderer internally to paint itself, not DrawString. Try this:

```cs
TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, text, dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font, location, dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor);
```